# Improve execution of mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have an Action collection with 19,348,086 documents so far.
Action has an index on 'rule' field.

When I tried to get documents with a given rule like this :

```
 db.actions.find({ rule: ObjectId("57b47749e823f9a804df7c86")}).explain("executionStats");
```

It takes almost 40 seconds to retrieve 18,904,044 documents.

FYI `db.actions.find({}).explain("executionStats");` is executed in 16 seconds.

Does it seem normal to you ? What can I do to improve the execution time ?

---

```
db.actions.find({ rule: ObjectId("57b47749e823f9a804df7c86")}).explain("executionStats");
```

Result:

```
{  
"queryPlanner":{  
    "plannerVersion":1,
    "namespace":"test.actions",
    "indexFilterSet":false,
    "parsedQuery":{  
        "rule":{  
            "$eq":ObjectId("57b47749e823f9a804df7c86")
        }
    },
    "winningPlan":{  
        "stage":"FETCH",
        "inputStage":{  
            "stage":"IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern":{  
                "rule":-1
            },
            "indexName":"rule_-1",
            "isMultiKey":false,
            "isUnique":false,
            "isSparse":false,
            "isPartial":false,
            "indexVersion":1,
            "direction":"forward",
            "indexBounds":{  
                "rule":[  
                    "[ObjectId('57b47749e823f9a804df7c86'), ObjectId('57b47749e823f9a804df7c86')]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans":[  
        . 
  . 
  .
    ]
},
"executionStats":{  
    "executionSuccess":true,
    "nReturned":18904044,
    "executionTimeMillis":39937,
    "totalKeysExamined":18904044,
    "totalDocsExamined":18904044,
    "executionStages":{  
        "stage":"FETCH",
        "nReturned":18904044,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate":7370,
        "works":18904045,
        "advanced":18904044,
        "needTime":0,
        "needYield":0,
        "saveState":147692,
        "restoreState":147692,
        "isEOF":1,
        "invalidates":0,
        "docsExamined":18904044,
        "alreadyHasObj":0,
        "inputStage":{  
            "stage":"IXSCAN",
            "nReturned":18904044,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate":2040,
            "works":18904045,
            "advanced":18904044,
            "needTime":0,
            "needYield":0,
            "saveState":147692,
            "restoreState":147692,
            "isEOF":1,
            "invalidates":0,
            "keyPattern":{  
                "rule":-1
            },
            "indexName":"rule_-1",
            "isMultiKey":false,
            "isUnique":false,
            "isSparse":false,
            "isPartial":false,
            "indexVersion":1,
            "direction":"forward",
            "indexBounds":{  
                "rule":[  
                    "[ObjectId('57b47749e823f9a804df7c86'), ObjectId('57b47749e823f9a804df7c86')]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined":18904044,
            "dupsTested":0,
            "dupsDropped":0,
            "seenInvalidated":0
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo":{  
    "host":"MacBook-Pro-de-Adrien.local",
    "port":27017,
    "version":"3.2.0",
    "gitVersion":"45d947729a0315accb6d4f15a6b06be6d9c19fe7"
},
"ok":1
}
```

Comment: what is average document size? are you loading documents on same server or via network connection?

Comment: @profesor79 Thx. avgObjSize =  207 and in my example, I'am loading documents from my local mongodb server.